# expect script error $argv not found

Tags: shell, expect

I have the following shell(/expect) script.

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c '
set user [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]
set ipaddr [lindex $argv 2]
set timeout 10
spawn ssh $user@$ipaddr mkdir -p ~/Tested
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "$password\r"
interact
'
```

when I run the script as follows

```
. test.sh abcd test 10.xx.xxx.xxx
```

It gives the following error

```
can't read "argv": no such variable
    while executing
"lindex $argv 0"
    invoked from within
"set user [lindex $argv 0]"
```

Does anybody know what the error is , if I replace [lindex $argv 0] lines with actual value the script runs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm no expert, but try running `expect -c '...' $1 $2 $3` in your shell script to pass those arguments along to expect.

Comment: @fwilson  If I do that I get can't                                          "read "argv": no such variable
    while executing
"lindex $argv 0"
    invoked from within
"set user [lindex $argv 0]"
couldn't read file "test": no such file or directory"

Comment: @tushR put $1 instead of { $argv 0 } , $2 instead of { $argv 1 } and so on

Comment: I believe expect only sets `$argv` /after/ it ran the commands specified with `-c` :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-c` flag in `expect` **provides a way of** **executing commands specified on the command line rather than in a script.**

In general, `-c` is flag is used in command line used to execute commands before a script takes control.

They are used as below.

```
expect -c "set debug 1" myscript.exp
```

Inside myscript.exp, you can check the value of this variable:

```
if [info exists debug] {
 puts "debugging mode: on"
}
else {
 set debug 0
 # imagine more commands here
 if $debug {puts "value of x = $x"}
}
```

When the script is run, it checks if debug is defined by evaluating `info exists`, a
Tcl command which returns 1 if the variable is defined or 0 if it is not. If it is defined,
the script can then test it later to determine if it should print debugging information internal to the script. The else clause sets debug to 0 just so that later a simple `if $debug` test can be used.

Now, lets come to your question. You are using the variable `argv` which is the command line argument list passed to some script and with `-c` flag in use, you cant make use of it since `argv` is intended to be used inside a script, not outside.

Instead of doing this way, you can put your code inside a script file and call the code as below.

```
expect yourscript.exp username pwd ip_address
```

If you still interested in command line arguments, then you can try what fwilson suggested in comments.

```
expect yourscript.exp $1 $2 $3
```

With this, yourscript.exp will get the arguments from the shell script.

Reference : [Exploring Expect](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fshop.oreilly.com%2Fproduct%2F9781565920903.do&ei=zx0ZVL3QFYmsPLuigbgH&usg=AFQjCNFr6RsLyrLy3jEwtgD_Txf-kQOtOw&bvm=bv.75558745,d.ZWU)