# Shell scripting : Giving error invalid command name "server1"

Tags: shell, unix, expect

I have written a shell script for double authentication.
This is giving an error while execution in if statement.

```
#!/usr/bin/Expect
#!/bin/bash
set cpPass "App12345"
set server [lindex $argv 0]
set pass "App12345@123"
set app "app1"
set appPass "app@1013"
spawn ssh user1@$server.corp.clll.com
expect {
        "(yes/no)?" {

                      send "yes\r"

                      expect "password:"

                      send "$cpPass\r"

                    }

        "password:" {
                       send "$pass\r"
                    }
     }
expect "bash"
send "su - $app\r"
expect "Password:"
send "$appPass\r"

if [ "$server" == "server1" ]
then
   send "cd /ngs/app/genevad/QA/site/distribution/servers1\r";
else
   send "sqlplus gqa_owner/App#789@dbgeneva01d.corp.clll.com:1700/app1D\r";
fi

interact
```

The error is like this on execution of command
./script.sh server1

```
invalid command name "server1"
    while executing
""$server" == "novello" "
    invoked from within
"if [ "$server" == "novello" ]"
    (file "./script.sh" line 28)
```

I have tried various combinations in if like :
if [ $server == "novello" ]
if [ $server -eq "novello" ]
if [ "$server" -eq "novello" ]
etc but still not working. Any suggestions/Solutions to it?

Comment: As per anubhava and dinesh answers , updated the script as follows : 1. removed #!/bin/bash    2. Changed code : if { $server == "server1" } {
   send "cd /ngs/app/genevad/QA/site/distribution/servers1\r";
} else {
   send "sqlplus gqa_owner/App#789@dbgeneva01d.corp.apple.com:1700/app1D\r";
}

Comment: Don't use `expect` for login `ssh`! Use `ssk-keygen` and share public keys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/Expect
#!/bin/bash
```

You **cannot have** 2 shebangs in same Unix script. Only first will be in effect and second will be ignored. Hence your script must be fully `expect` compliant script (since that is first one here - should be lowercase `expect` though).

Moment you try to use a `bash` syntax in it, you will get errors since that `bash` specific script will be interpreted by `expect`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the code `[$server == "server1"]` with `{$server == "server1"}`. As anubhava pointed out, u don't need 2 executeables name in the shebang. You can use only `bash`. Include all your expect code with `-c` flag. To know more about how to use expect with  `-c` flag, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26607110/974155